# Get last input character in a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I wanted  constantly keep track of what is entered in a JTextArea, thus I want to get the last input character in a JTextArea everytime the user type something.

I am able to come out with the entire working program. However the way I get the last input character is this:

```
textArea.getText().charAt(textArea.getText().length()-1);
```

This way, I always have to get the entire string of text from JTextArea first.

**My question is**: Is there anyway better way to allow me to get the last input character without getting the entire text from the JTextArea first?

Comment: Why do you think it is a problem to 'get the entire text'?

Comment: I am thinking about the `getDocument()` and make use of the document object.

Comment: @isnot2bad Don't you think in terms of implementation, something is very wrong if I have to get the entire text for every key stroke I press? What if the text is a million characters long? Won't it affect the efficiency?

Comment: @camickr No problem, you can skip this as of the past, you never like to answer my question but talk about something else.

Comment: @user3437460 It depends if the `JTextArea` has to build up the string every time you request it or if it already holds an internal string that is just passes (by reference). But see my answer for a possible solution.

Comment: @isnot2bad Since Strings are immutable and if I use the getText() method, it will probably be returning a copy of the String and not the reference. Thus, I was thinking it might not be a very good choice to get the entire text, when I am only interested in the last input character. what do you think?

Comment: @user3437460 Immutability is the reason why it is _not_ necessary to return a copy, because it is not possible to modify it outside of the class and cause side effects!

Comment: @isnot2bad So do you I worry too much on the efficiency issues and my code given above is good enough to do the job? If you can reply this with a good reason, I will accept your answer. thanks. Please give me a clear yes/no answer. :)

Comment: Getting the whole string is a terrible solution given that are much easier ways to do this. The Document doesn't even store the text in a String. It has to parse the Element structure of the Document and then rebuild the text every time.

Comment: @user3437460 How is this related to my answer? My answer gives another solution that does _not_ return the 'entire text'.

Comment: @camickr Are you trying to say you have a better solution than isnot2bad's ?

Comment: Well your requirement isn't completely clear: `I want to get the last input character in a JTextArea everytime the user type something.` How do you currently know when the user types something? What happens if the user pastes text into the text area? In this case there will be more than one character that was entered.

Comment: @camickr I am using DocumentListener. So if more than 1 character was pasted, it will detect it as well.

Comment: Then I would just use the answer given. The DocumentEvent has access to the Document and you just use the getText() method. I don't know why you haven't "accepted" this answer already?

Answer (score 2):

You can query an arbitrary part of a `JTextArea`:

```
Document doc = textArea.getDocument();
String lastCharAsString = doc.getText(doc.getLength() - 1, 1);
```

If you even care about creating a one-character-`String` every time, this might be another solution which does not even create a `String` instance:

```
Segment seg = new Segment(); // can be reused
Document doc = textArea.getDocument();
doc.getText(doc.getLength() - 1, 1, seg);
char last = seg.last(); // equal to seg.first()
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a DocumentListener?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners
Underlying object for a JTextArea is a Document.
So you could trap the required update event obtain the last input character and
store it in a variable.
Assuming this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This is the most appropriate answer! The ``DocumentEvent`` objects also give you access to the underlying document (``DocumentEvent.getDocument()``), the location of the change (``DocumentEvent.getOffset()``) and the length (``DocumentEvent.getLength()``).